# Connection error while installing mongodb on Fedora 28

Tags: mongodb, installation, fedora

I have been trying to install Mongodb but it keeps failing midway. When the download is complete, installation fails with a connection error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-08-17T12:26:33.340+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-08-17T12:26:33.340+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

What I've tried:
1. Changing the port:
`mongo --port 4332`
but it doesn't connect still:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:4332/
2018-08-17T12:32:55.743+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:4332, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-08-17T12:32:55.743+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:4332, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

2. Reinstalling the DB shows up as complete but I still can't start it. Check out the screenshot

[image: An image showing an error while installing mongodb]

3. Checking for any config files in `/etc/mongo*` or `/var/lib/`: there is none.
   **Note**: There's no mongod service available too.

Comment: Did you start the mongod process?

Comment: It's not available.

Comment: the mongo shell is an utility to connect to a mongod server. if there is no mongod server, mongo shell will never be able to connect to it.
the mongod service should have been installed at the same time that the mongo shell.

Comment: I know, which is why I mentioned that the installation fails halfway.

Comment: it is strange, the fist snippet do not show a failed installation. it show a failed execution of the mongo shell (because there is no mongod at 127.0.0.1:27017)
if simply running "mongod" do not work, It is possible mongod is not in the PATH variable (would surprise me if "mongo" work, but it is possible). I would try finding where MongoDB was installed and find the mongod file

Comment: in debian, I can do "mongod" in command line to start the mongod.
I can also do "sudo service mongod start" to start mongod as a service (using the service utility who may or may not be different in fedora).
using "mongod" direcly should alway work, though.

Comment: which is also strange because there's no mongo directory in `/var/lib/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178209/discussion-between-felix-brunet-and-samuel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the installation seem to have worked, but the mongod was not started.

MongoDB need two element :

the "mongo" shell utility, who is used to connect to the database direcly
the "mongod" service, who is the true database programs.

to start the mongod, simply use a cmd and use the "mongod" command. this command may fail if :

- the port is already used (default is 27017)
- the dbpath directory was not created (default is /data/db)

Fedora repository do not install both at the same time.
the shell is in the repository under the "mongodb" name
the server is under the name "mongodb-server"

so to install both, you need to do

```
dnf install mongodb mongodb-server
```

and you can then start the mongod service with

```
sudo service mongod start
```

[more information](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/database/mongodb/about.html)

Comment: Why is it that the ` service mongod` service isn't available? I can only start it with `mongod`?